# how to change the image in the array when we click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a little problem

I want every time I click on an image, my main image will change according to the image that I click on

I want to click on the image below, the image above changes

[image]

this is my code

```
import React from "react";

const SingleProductComponent = ({ list }) => {
  return (
 
      
                <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                  <div className="SingProduct__img">
                    <div className="SingProduct__inner">
                      <div className="inner__data">
                        {list.image && (
                          <img
                            src={list.image[0]}
                            alt=""
                            className="inner__data-img"
                          />
                        )}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    {list.image && (
                      <div className="SingleProduct__thumb">
                        <div className="SingleProduct__thumb-list">
                          {list.image.map((e, index) => (
                            <div className="thumb__list-item" key={index}>
                              <img src={e} className="thumb__item-img" alt="" />
                            </div>
                          ))}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a `state` to the selected image `index`, and then according to the `clicked` item, you change the value.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

const SingleProductComponent = ({ list }) => {
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);

  const changeSelectedItem = (index) => {
    setSelectedIndex(index)
  }
  return (
                <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                  <div className="SingProduct__img">
                    <div className="SingProduct__inner">
                      <div className="inner__data">
                        {list.image && (
                          <img
                            src={list.image[selectedIndex]}
                            alt=""
                            className="inner__data-img"
                          />
                        )}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    {list.image && (
                      <div className="SingleProduct__thumb">
                        <div className="SingleProduct__thumb-list">
                          {list.image.map((e, index) => (
                            <div className="thumb__list-item" key={index} onClick={() => changeSelectedItem(index)}>
                              <img src={e} className="thumb__item-img" alt="" />
                            </div>
                          ))}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </div>
  )
}
```